# Regarding column not showing correctly on Jupiter notebook

Tags: python, macos, csv, jupyter-notebook, export-to-csv

First picture 'N159K' shows how it is looking like and the second picture shows how it should look like 'H2mgz'. Why is this happening and what can I do to solve this?
When I run the code on my machine it shows like the first picture 'N159K'. I have attached the pictures for reference.
Please help...

1. https://i.stack.imgur.com/N159K.jpg
2. https://i.stack.imgur.com/H2mgz.jpg

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  Instead of linking to images, please type out your code in the post.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a jupyter notebook issue, you are reading the data wrong.

The delimiter for your csv files are `;` but when you read within pandas, the default is `,`. So you should specify your delimiter:

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep=";")
```